# How to translate commerce-order:status in Drupal Commerce?

Tags: commerce

I created Rules for receiving e-mail when you change the status of the order.
E-mail send but not translated.
I created a rule in Action Send Email. In the present rule in the message I created a PHP script

PHP
    $status="none";
    if("[commerce-order:status]"=="checkout_shipping") $status="text1 text1 text1 text1";
    else if("[commerce-order:status]"=="checkout_checkout") $status="text2 text2 text2 text1";
    else
   $status="none none"

Given the status of your order: $status

The message that comes is "none none";

I do not know what's going on. I get tired of it already the second day.
Thank you for your help